# Spree User information

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I'm using Spree as an eCommerce solution for a website that I am building and need to customize the layout, the deface option is great but I already have a layout for the rest of my application that I want to use so there is no change between the main part of my site and the store.

Having looked through the spree source code I have been able to transfer most of the infrastructure over to my own new template but I have hit one stumbling block. In the default template above the search box there are  login/account and logout links which based on some digging through the code is rendered in the 'header' partial which itself renders the nav bar which renders the search bar partial, and the main nav bar which shows the links to home and the shopping cart, but nowhere mentions the user in/out stuff. Commenting out the rendering of the header partial removes all of this stuff but also the user information, which as far as I can tell isn't mentioned anywhere...

Does anyone know where in the default spree layout it implements this code for showing a login/logout account link, I could do this relatively simply with basic links to it but would rather understand how Spree implements this itself and I'm trying to keep my layout compatible with any updates to the core code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Edited: For clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found code in the RDR theme that explains this, still not sure why it doesn't show up in the default spree code, maybe a data hook?

The way RDR does it:

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= link_to t('logout'), destroy_user_session_path, :class => "cart" %>
  <%= link_to t('my_account'), account_path, :class => "cart" %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to t('log_in'), login_path, :class => "cart" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

On version **3.0.1** of Spree and maybe on other older versions the user functionality is not handled by the core itself. Users are handled by the [Spree Auth (Devise)](https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise) Spree extension. This extension is included by default on new Spree apps. The extension uses a [deface override](https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise/blob/3-0-stable/app/overrides/auth_shared_login_bar.rb) to add this functionality. Interestingly enough the partial used by this override is not on the extension itself but rather on the Spree frontend files. I assume to make this component reusable should you wish to implement your custom user module. This is the code of the partial:

```
<% if spree_current_user %>
  <li><%= link_to Spree.t(:my_account), spree.account_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to Spree.t(:logout), spree.logout_path %></li>
<% else %>
  <li id="link-to-login"><%= link_to Spree.t(:login), spree.login_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

override menu with

```
<% if current_user %>
    <%= link_to t(:logout), spree.destroy_user_session_path %>
    <%= link_to t(:my_account), spree.account_path %>
<% else %>
   <%= link_to t(:login), spree.login_path %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of **Spree 2.3.2** same thing can be done with:

```
          <h2>Your Account</h2>
          <ul>
            <% if spree_current_user %>            
              <li><%= link_to t('My Account'), account_path, :class => "cart" %></li>       
            <% else %>                
              <li><%= link_to t('Log In'), login_path, :class => "cart" %></li>
              <li><%= link_to t('Sign Up'), registration_path, :class => "cart" %></li>
            <% end %>              
          </ul>
```